# Questions Regarding Handling of Received SMS

Tags: android, sms

I have managed to successfully write a little test app that can
receive and send SMS, but got a couple of questions. (That's 'cos part
of the code I copied from elsewhere and I would like to understand
better).

1. In my `AndroidManifest` as well as the sub-class of
   `BroadcastReceiver`, there is reference to the string literal
   `"android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"`. However, I couldn't find
   any reference in the API that mentions this. Could someone point me to
   some reference that lists/explains these?
2. As part of getting the message from the Intent, I did this:

   `Object[] pdus = (Object[]) intent.getExtras().get("pdus");`

Again this question is related to the use of hardcoded string literal.
Where is the string `"pdus"` listed and described?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What version of Android are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are not finding those things is because they are not part of the SDK and therefore are [not designed to be used by applications](http://www.google.de/interstitial?url=http://www.androidguys.com/2009/12/14/code-pollution-reaching-past-the-sdk/). It is possible that those `Intents` will be altered in future releases of Android, or perhaps not used on certain devices.

Comment: i see... so basically there is no way to handle incoming SMSes by just using the official APIs?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. You can definitely send SMSes via SmsManager.

Comment: There was support for receiving SMS messages in earlier versions of Android.  I haven't kept up, but it seems they've pulled support for it.